# Directory structure on Linux EC2

Tags: linux, directory, amazon-ec2

First, I'm a complete newbie to Linux and Tomcat. I'm not technical either. I get my stuff done by feeling my way around the dark until things work. I do read a lot though.

I have a dev machine (Windows 7) with the following config:

```
c:\dev\apache\
c:\dev\tomcat7\
c:\dev\sites\site1
c:\dev\sites\site2
```

I just created an Amazon Linux EC2 instance and I want to upload my stuff and have the same structure.

1. Is there any reason I shouldn't replicate my structure from dev to the EC2 instance?
2. Are there any security concerns or things to keep in mind now that I'm using Linux?

I read that a) it's better to install Tomcat in /usr/local/tomcat and b) that if I am installing Tomcat myself, I should create a user group for it.

I usually login to ec2 and type `sudo su` then I do a wget to download and install Tomcat.

Comment: Why Linux? I would probably suggest that you get some sort of windows instance and work from that point before moving on to Linux.

Comment: @Rilindo, well, I've never managed a server in my life. Linux or Windows. I'm feeling my way in the dark here. My dev machine setup never exposed me to any of this stuff. So why not just start with Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. HTTPd and Tomcat should be placed in their normal locations, but your sites can be placed under `/srv` (e.g. `/srv/sites/site1`).
2. Certainly. Lots. Far too many to put in an answer. The short form is to disabled unneeded services, block unused ports, and make sure your software is up to date.

Comment: Thank you! Apache gets installed automatically. I don't specify the location. But what is the "normal" location for Tomcat?

Comment: If the distro installs it, `/usr`. If you install it, `/usr/local`. If a third-party installs it, `/opt/<somename>`. [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html)